# Segmentation fault while installing ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso

Tags: virtualbox

While installing ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso in Oracle VirtualBox, got the below error, I have 140GB free disk memory in my laptop. Why is this error coming often, tried installing multiple times, getting the same error. How can I fix this error and install Ubuntu 20.04?

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Did you verified the ISO?

Comment: Oracle vbox can misbehave if the VM is given insufficient RAM; Oracle report it's a user error (not their product).  The link to verify the ISO as @ChanganAuto suggests is https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0

Comment: I gave 6GB RAM, my laptop has 32GB overall RAM size.

Comment: You may want to try different flavor ISO - for example MATE - http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mate/releases/20.04.2.0/release/ubuntu-mate-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso .